# "Direct it": which meaning is right?

Tags: meaning-in-context, lyrics

> Tell me your secrets, all of the creepy shit.
>   That's how I know it's true.
>   Baby, **direct it**, name in the credits,
>   like the movies do.
>
> <sub>*from "Imagine" by Ariana Grande*</sub>

I have done research and found that it could be of these meanings:

1. *THEATRE, CINEMA* to be in charge of making a movie or program, or getting a play ready for performance, especially by telling the actors and technical staff what to do
2. Talking directly towards someone

I wish I could know what you guys think of this, what "direct it" means, I'm confused here.

Comment: Thank you for giving some idea of the context, and also for indicating that you have tried to find out the meaning.  Can you give a little more:  name of the book/script; name of the author; context in which this is said?

Comment: It's from the song "Imagine" by Ariana Grande, she says that at the end, trying to understand if she's referring to be direct at the point of telling all the liars about her lover or if it is about telling him to direct the scene, but I don't get why it could be the second one.

Comment: understanding lyrics of songs can be fraught with opinion!

Answer (score 1):

It must be the THEATRE, CINEMA. This is because it refers to 'The Movies' where the director is the one in charge. Also 'Credits' refers to movies, the list of the cast and all the people who helped make the movie.